# spring-security requestMap for actions

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I'd like to employ dynamic request maps to secure controller actions.
This works fine for URLs as

- `/<controller>/show/*`
- `<controller>/list`

but fails with a "springSecurity.denied.message" e.g. for

- `/<controller>/create`

when the instance shall be saved. The create-url requires:

- `/<controller>/save`

to be added to the requestMap - then it does work.
For "delete" and "edit", I was unable to find a solution.

???What is the appropriate set of requestMap entries to allow for actions "edit" and "delete"???

Annotation can solve this - but the requestMap approach should also work.

```
STATUS
Grails version: 2.2.2
PLUGIN
springSecurityCore - 1.2.7.3 using SecurityConfigType.Requestmap
```

Comment: What is the actual problem here?

Comment: I am looking for the requestMap entries that allow ROLE_USER to list and show instances and allow USER_EDITOR to create, edit and delete instances.